# clicking on a schedule item no longer pops up org-agenda

Tags: org-mode

In the good old days (ie last week before I did a `M-x package-list-package` `U` `x`) when I clicked on a `SCHEDULED: <...>` link, it would popup the `org-agenda` view. Now it does nothing and displays `No link found`. Is there a way to restore the old behaviour?

`C-c C-o` `org-open-at-point` also fails in the same way yet the docstring for that says:

```
On top of syntactically correct links, this function also tries
to open links and time-stamps in comments, node properties, and
keywords if point is on something looking like a timestamp or
a link.
```

... so I don't think I'm trippin!

EDIT 20190112: I tried with `emacs -Q` but it made no difference.

I got a copy of org-mode-release_9.1.14 and the good old behaviour is restored. So I'm leaning towards a regression that's crept in.

Comment: i would file an issue/bugreport

Comment: Yeah - I have done. Haven't heard back yet.

Comment: Apparently it has been fixed upstream - but I have no idea how to get it into melpa. It'll no doubt flow through in the next update cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix: https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/f9596eb47219794ae66c29bf4a091c478ccf5830 which can be back-ported to the latest release_9.2 / org-plus-contrib-20181230